# Python 3.11 Typing for multiple inheritance models

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I want to implement typing for a group of related classes that share a common metaclass (`AMeta`), there are two 'de facto' abstract parent classes:

- `A` (:type[AMeta])
- `ADerived` - that also inherits from another class `C`.

Finally there are actual implementation models of `ADerived` (`D1`, `D2`, ... these are dynamically created) and `A` (`E`, `F`, ...) parent classes.

The implementations of `A` (`E`, `F`) have also a class variable of type `ADerived` (`_DerivedModel`) and the problem I have is trying to make `mypy` infer the correct type for them.

I know this piece of code might not make sense, but the actual implementation is more complex and the derived models are dynamically created. Here's a simplification of it:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Type, ClassVar

_BModel = TypeVar("_BModel", bound="ADerived")


class C:
    pass


class AMeta(type):
    @property
    def BModel(cls: Type[A]) -> Type[_BModel]:
        return cls._DerivedModel


# Abstract Models
class A(metaclass=AMeta):
    _DerivedModel: ClassVar[Type[_BModel]]


class ADerived(A, C):
    pass


# Derived Models (this models are dynamically created)
class D1(ADerived):
    pass


class D2(ADerived):
    pass


# Implementations


class E(A):
    _DerivedModel = D1


class F(A):
    _DerivedModel = D2


MyDerived1 = E.BModel  # Should be infered by mypy as type[D1]
MyDerived2 = F.BModel  # Should be infered by mypy as type[D2]
```

Comment: Please check the edit whether I haven't edited something out incorrectly. I attempted to correct the formatting but had a bit of trouble distinguishing what the parenthesis meant.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5144

Answer (score -2):

Issue arises from trying to use type hints in a way that is not directly supported by mypy. One way to handle this scenario more effectively is to provide explicit type annotations to help mypy understand the relationships between the classes.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Type, TypeVar, ClassVar, cast

_BModel = TypeVar("_BModel", bound="ADerived")


class C:
    pass

    
class AMeta(type):
    @property
    def BModel(cls: Type[A]) -> Type[_BModel]:
        return cast(Type[_BModel], cls._DerivedModel)
    
    
# Abstract Models
class A(metaclass=AMeta):
    _DerivedModel: ClassVar[Type[_BModel]]


class ADerived(A, C):
    pass


# Derived Models (these models are dynamically created)
class D1(ADerived):
    pass


class D2(ADerived):
    pass


# Implementations

class E(A):
    _DerivedModel: ClassVar[Type[D1]] = D1


class F(A):
    _DerivedModel: ClassVar[Type[D2]] = D2


MyDerived1: Type[D1] = E.BModel  # Inferred as type[D1]
MyDerived2: Type[D2] = F.BModel  # Inferred as type[D2]
```

Comment: DV: you can't use an unbound type variable like this (in `AMeta.BModel`), and generic metaclasses (necessary to make this work) are [not truly supported](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11672).

Comment: it must be 'infered' by the type checker, but here you are making it explicit. In the real application this is done dynamically so i dont know the type at build time.